# partial() substituting functions in python

Tags: python, function

I have the code below, which works for me. My question is generally speaking why does it work? How does the `partial()` function know that the f in `difference_quotient()` is a function. In `partial()` it gets substituted for `x*x` which would mean `return(x*x(x+h)-x*x(x))/h`. But this would change the output beeing wrong.

```py
from functools import partial
def difference_quotient(f, x, h):
    return(f(x+h)-f(x))/h
def square(x):
    return x*x

derivative_estimate1 = partial(difference_quotient, square, h=0.00001)

print(derivative_estimate1(5))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So `partial` is a class which generates a new function with some arguments pre-filled out (in other words, you don't need to provide them).  The first argument you pass to`partial` is the function you will be running, namely `difference_quotient` in your case.  Then, the `square` function is passed in as the actual "first" argument to `difference_quotient` and `h` is specified via a keyword.  When you then run `derivative_estimate1`, it runs `difference_quotient(square, 5, h=0.00001)` where the 5 is passed in from your new call.

For positional arguments, it will fill in from left-to-right, but since you specified h=0.00001, it filled h instead of x, meaning when you call the function again, the only argument you can provide is `x`.

If you try only passing in `difference_quotient` to `partial` like so:

`derivative_estimate1 = partial(difference_quotient)`

and then run it like this:

`print(derivative_estimate1(5))`

It will complain because you didn't pass enough arguments.

**Edit:** 
To better directly answer your question about Python knowing it's a function:

Python doesn't know anything, inherently, about it's variables.  It only knows that you intend to use whatever `f` is as a function.

If I made the call like this:

`derivative_estimate1 = partial(difference_quotient, 5, h=0.00001)`
`print(derivative_estimate1(5))`

I get an error where Python says it tried to call a function on a number.

`TypeError: 'int' object is not callable`

There's no "magic" Python does to "know" its a function.  It just says "Hey, you are trying to call this argument you passed in, so it must be a function."

> In partial() it gets substituted for x*x

This is not really correct.  `square` is passed in as a function, and then you just call that function in your code.

I hope that clears things up for you.

Comment: I see, that is what I was thinking! thank you for clarifying! The question I still have is how does `f`get replaced as it's is replaced by the function `x*x` but `difference_quotient(f, x, h)` itself has an `x`. Is it just how python works, it recognizes the `f`with the open parantheses as a function?

I hope I made my question more clear :s

Comment: Well, that's sort of what I was trying to get at.  It doesn't actually know at all.  If you passed your arguments in a different order it wouldn't work.  Python doesn't actually know at all, it's just the fact that you are trying to call it that it works.

If you did `derivative_estimate1 = partial(difference_quotient, 2, 3)` it would fail once you called it because Python has no idea the types of any variables until you try using them.  So unless you did a type check, you could easily pass an integer for `f`.  I'll ammend my answer.

Comment: @SebastianOrtmann If my answer helped you, would you accept it as the answer?

Happy to know you got it figured it out though :)